How to get excel to display a certain part of sheet, depending on the value of another cell
looking for some help, hopefully this makes sense!
I am trying to make a file that allows the user to select the number of people attending an event, and it will automatically show the seating plan for this number of people.
I have made an excel sheet that contains a drop-down list. This list is a series of numbers ranging from 30 to 8.
I have also made a number of "seating plans" on the same sheet which correspond to the number of people. Essentially, I would like the user to select a number and for excel to display the cells that contain that specific floor plan.
For example, the user wants to know the floor plan for 20 people. They select this from the drop-down list, and they are shown cells C7 to O33, which contain the correct floor plan.
Really hope this makes sense and appreciate any help!

An alternative might be having the floor plans on different tabs, and then opening a tab after selection.

You haven't written exactly what you want to display in different cases, but maybe you'll be inspired by this proposal.
The list in cell B3 refers to a range of cells: D3:D8. The addresses of the areas are in the range E3:E8.
The result in cell A10 is obtained by using a dynamic formula.
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP($B$3,$D$3:$E$8,2))

This requires Excel with dynamic formulas (at least 2021 or 365).
Values are displayed without formatting.


Here's an example using CHOOSE to select ranges depending on the number of seats selected:
=CHOOSE(XMATCH(num_attendees,num_seats),A1:A2,_20,B1:B2) & ""



For ease of use you could define named ranges

though you could use A1:A2,_20, B1:B2 etc. defining a name such as _20 for 20 person seating will make the maintenance easier


choices for number seats is specified in T2:V2 and named num_seats (needs to adjusted for your values)



To display the seating for the selection

select range to hold the largest seating range
in the example it is $R$6:$AJ$56
using conditional formatting to show the range could be useful




